# Jsp charset encoding issue

Tags: java, html, jsp, web, encoding

I make some web program

Using tomcat, jsp, java
In AIX SERVER

In my jsp file
I have a code
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=euc-kr" @>

But, it show ??? Like this.
If i success it have to be print 성공 like this

I want to use utf-8 but my environment can't agree it.
So i have to use euc-kr encoding

I already tried

Add pageEncoding="euc-kr"

Change server.xml --add URIEncoding

Change tomcat web.xml --add filter

Add meta tag in jsp

I think i don't nee set.request because data is fine

Problem is just character in jsp.

If i didn't do nothing it show
¿¤0》 like this

I don't know what can i do now..

Comment: Have a read of https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html especially section 3

Comment: Thanks I read that. But my problem is not request data

Comment: Just jsp-html data is show ????

Comment: I guess every source file should be in this encoding; `javac` should be used with option `-encoding euc_kr`; at run-time `-Dfile.encoding=euc_kr` option should be passed to `java` Also the `<%@page` could be `<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC_KR" pageEncoding="EUC_KR" %>`